# Why am I getting 99% accuracy when using a Linear Regression model to predict stock prices in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to predict stock prices in python using a linear regression model. I split the data using train_test_split so from what I understand, my test data should not be in my training data so I do not understand why the model gives 100% accuracy.

Here is my code:

```
X = RMV.drop('Close', axis=1)
y = RMV['Close']`

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

reg_preds = reg.predict(X_test)
```

When I run cross validation to test for accuracy using this code I get a value of 1.00.

```
scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(reg, X_test, y_test, cv=10)
print ("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() / 2))
```

For reference, here is a sample of the data I've used:

```
            Close       SMA         EMA         MACD        Upper Band  Middle Band Lower Band  RSI
Date                                
2010-02-18  60.900002   57.335715   57.419887   2.099073    64.842238   55.4075 45.972762   60.517959
2010-02-19  61.000000   57.967857   57.897236   2.215288    65.422290   55.9000 46.377710   60.672590
2010-02-22  62.099998   58.560714   58.457604   2.368843    66.047128   56.4675 46.887872   62.416318
2010-02-23  61.200001   59.117857   58.823257   2.390360    66.386746   57.0000 47.613254   60.069541
2010-02-24  60.900002   58.539286   59.100156   2.356046    66.504379   57.5425 48.580621   59.269579
```

Where am I going wrong?

Update: Accuracy seems to be the wrong indicator so I've switched to using MSE as suggested by the replies:

```
print('Mean Squared Error: ', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true=y_test, y_pred=lm_preds))
print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f' % metrics.r2_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=lm_preds))
```

This gives me approximately MSE = 13-15 depending on the run and R2 = 0.999 which is still very high. The MSE isn't actually as high as it seems since the average stock price is around 600 or so. The model still seems to perform too well.

I was using Rightmove stock data from 2010-2020. I just switched to using a more volatile stock (PMO.L) from 2010-2020 and 2019-2020 and I also removed 5/7 indicators I was using.

For 2010-2020 the model gives an MSE of 69 (relatively low compared to stock price) and 0.999 R2. However, for 2019-2020, the model does seem to be a bit worse with an MSE of 15.5 and R2 of 0.82 which is significantly lower than before. Considering this is just one year's worth of data however, it still seems to perform too well.

Here are samples of the feature data used to train the model for the new stock:

2010-2020:

```
            SMA         EMA
Date        
2010-02-18  266.214286  266.857731
2010-02-19  266.910714  268.110034
2010-02-22  267.303571  269.428696
2010-02-23  267.589286  269.838203
2010-02-24  264.660714  270.659776
```

2011-2020:

```
            SMA         EMA
Date        
2019-02-18  73.425000   73.791397
2019-02-19  73.632143   74.052544
2019-02-20  73.785715   74.325538
2019-02-21  73.953572   74.335466
2019-02-22  73.928572   74.330738
```

Comment: Are you training with the test result?

Comment: @AdrianMaire Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm training with a subset of the data. I'm not retraining the model with the results if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Lohith I tried that and it gave me this error:

`Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Comment: @desertnaut Hi, I don't think I have posted any code in the comments but I'm not sure as I'm now. Could you please specify what you want me to change about the title? Also, this is the value of scores: 
`array([0.99923183, 0.99949965, 0.99950441, 0.99947971, 0.99910287,
       0.99970884, 0.99931352, 0.99958207, 0.99938308, 0.99966785])`

Comment: so, it is not 1.0, or "100%", as you claim in the title!

Comment: @desertnaut My bad, the output of the print function approximated to 1.0 so I got confused. However, is this still not way too high?

Comment: What you actually calculate here is the R-squared, which is not very meaningful in such predictive settings. Try MSE, as shown in the answer below.

Comment: The features you use are probably not available at prediction time (i.e. you don't know the value of tomorrow's EMA from today). It means that you cannot directly use them for training. There are many approaches but the most straightforward one is to just use lagged values (i.e. shift the features by one row).

Answer (score 0):

When you did:

```
scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(lm, X_test, y_test, cv=10)
```

I assume that you defined before `lm` (I can't see it). You need to know what are you doing with `cross_val_score`. You are creating 10 different models with each `X_test` split, and then try it with his respective `y_test`. So you can't say that your `reg` model trained with `x_train` and `y_train` is overfitting because you are not evaluating it. Anyway, this indicates you that probably you will have also overfitting in you trained model.

To see if your reg model is overfitted, evaluated it with `X_test` like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

test_prediction = reg.predict(x_test)

print('Mean Squared Error: ', mean_squared_error(y_true=y_test, y_pred=test_prediction))
print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f'
      % r2_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=test_prediction))
```

If you want to to keep doing cross validation use the full X and Y (without splitting between train and test):

```
scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(lm, X, y, cv=10)  # Note I changed values of X and y
print ("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() / 2))
```

Finally, you have to be aware that you are in a **time series** problem (you have date). And linear regression is not a good model to deal with date. If you want to keep using Linear Regression I would recommend drop this feature. If you want to keep it, use ARMA or ARIMA models because they deal much better for time series data

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. `lm` was supposed to be `reg` which I forgot to update. For the cross validation, I was following a guide I found online and it explained it differently however I now see why it is not suitable. As for Linear Regression being bad for time series data, I'm doing this for a project so it being bad isn't particularly an issue as long as it can be explained. However, when you say I should drop this feature are you referring to the fact that it's time series and how may I go about doing this?

Comment: Using the updated cross validation code I'm getting an accuracy of 0.94 which still seems too high. Also, when calculating MSE I get approximately 13.06 however for the coefficient of determination I get 0.999, so approximately 1, which seems to suggest a perfect fit which does not seem correct.

Comment: @pystonks MSE is the correct metric to use here, and I guess it does *not* signify a "perfect fit"

Comment: @desertnaut Yes that's what I was thinking. I just do not understand why the coefficient of determination comes out to 1 when the model is clearly not perfect as the high MSE suggests. From the reading I've done, MSE and R2 are often used together and tend to have an inverse relationship however it's the opposite in this case which does not make sense.

Comment: If you drop "date" feature, you are not working anymore with time series. Then your model should be more correct. You can drop doing the same you did for creating X, where your dropped the "close" feature. Once you have done that, can you show which score did you obtain with test data (not doing cross validation) on MSE and R2.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat Date was set as the index so I reset the index and dropped the Date column. When I ran the script I got the same R2 value as before.

Comment: I have now realize it was as index, my bad, the idea was not to use it in the model. Can you edit your question adding what you have done? Including this last scrip you run and output you obtained.